# Android Studio SDK download location

Tags: android, android-studio

Ok, so my questions not really about programming, but it concerns Android Studio so I thought I'd get help from here. Does anyone know where Android Studio initially downloads SDKs? 
I don't have a very powerful setup, when I downloaded Android Studio I only had about 30gb in my C:Drive and 70gb in D: Drive. 
When I opened Android Studio the first thing I did was, ofc, download the SDKs that I needed. I set the SDK location to D:/sdk Drive. 
The problem with that was when it was downloading, I was doing idle stuff, the computer suddenly prompted me that it nearly had no space left. I opened My Computer and saw that C: only had 1gb left. Which was stupid! I chose D: as my SDK location. Now since this couldn't be, and my computer was lagging like hell because of this, I had to uninstall Android Studio, but now the new problem is that I got "some" memory back, but only 9gb! I literally lost 20gb of memory without knowing where it went. 
My guess is that it's from those uninstalled, undeleted SDKs, or something. Correct me if I'm wrong? I wanna know if there's a way for me to find those unwanted data. I still plan on reInstalling Android Studio but maybe another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Altho thumbs up to Matthias Wenz, since he pointed me to the right direction. It's in "AppData\local\temp" if anyone's lookign for them too.

[image: location of SDK download]

Answer (score 4):

General answer if you still have Android Studio installed You can check the download location of the Android SDK from Android Studio in case you have it installed ( `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK` ).

In my case on a Windows machine it was `C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` – so you might have a look in this folder.

Comment: Thanks you. The SDK Zips or whatever were downloaded to AppData\local\temp.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows OS, you can find them in the following addresses:

```
%temp%\PackageOperationXX
```

Or

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperationXX
```

like:

```
%temp%\PackageOperation01
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01
```